# Como obter link de qualquer ancora, usando expressão regular?

Tags: php, regex

Eu uso esse código para capturar links de uma determinada pagina:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);    
$resultado = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match_all('/<a href="/(.*)"/i', $resultado, $outros);
```

Porém, essa expressão regular deixa de fora links como por exemplo:

```
<a name="exemplo" href="link.php"></a>
```

E se eu tirar o `<a` e deixar só o `href` por exemplo:

```
preg_match_all('/href="/(.*)"/i', $resultado, $outros);
```

ai vai pegar coisas indevidas como links de css por exemplo:

```
<link href="link.css">
```

Qual a expressão regular ideal para capturar todos os `href` dos elementos `a` sem ter o risco de capturar `href` de elementos que nao sao `a`, como `css` por exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta dessa forma, ignorando o que esta entre `a` e `href`:

```
preg_match_all('/<a.*href="(.*)"/i', $resultado, $outros);
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Muito Obrigado amigo. PERFEITO!